# Setting up Java Application FloreantPOS access to Postgresql errors...org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException

Tags: database, postgresql, jdbc, ubuntu-18.04, java-11

Machine is running:
Ubuntu Linux 5.3.0-62-generic #56~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP
psql 12.3
openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14

I am trying to setup a Java app to connect to a PostgreSQL DB. I have thoroughly tested the database side and am very positive that the issue is not on the DB side. I have also tried using the application using a MariaDB just to eliminate any issues.

On the other side, I have tested the application with its own built Derby DB which seems to work just fine. Which chances are I will just end up using if I cannot figure out this issue.

However, whether using PostgreSQL or MariaDB (MySQL); I get the following errors:

```
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
ERROR: 11-Jul-2020 00:15:35: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
ERROR: 11-Jul-2020 00:15:35: com.floreantpos.util.DatabaseConnectionException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
```

I will attach the full log as it includes many more lines, however, I believe the issue is with this PooledConnection & possibly missing some sort of library for Java or path to library for the application to function properly.

Can anyone point me into a general direction.

I am familiar enough with Postgres & Mysql and have had a DB consultant look closely at that setup which seems to be functioning properly.

However, I do not know very much about Java or requirement to run such program connections to local or remote DB servers?

More error that continues to repeat:

```
ERROR: 11-Jul-2020 15:15:46: could not get database metadata
java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:65)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:527)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1300)
    at com.floreantpos.model.dao._RootDAO.reInitialize(_RootDAO.java:252)
    at com.floreantpos.util.DatabaseUtil.initialize(DatabaseUtil.java:508)
    at com.floreantpos.main.Application.initializeSystem(Application.java:160)
    at com.floreantpos.main.Application.start(Application.java:136)
    at com.floreantpos.main.Main.main(Main.java:58)
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@3be4fcc0 -- timeout at awaitAvailable()
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1317)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace. What you're posting is incomplete, so we don't know what the actual problem is.

Comment: I am trying to figure the best way without posting in the body. Please give me a few minutes.

Comment: I included much without repeating. This repeats over and over in the log files. I am happy to run Java with any specific options to help you troubleshoot it further. Like I mentioned; I am a complete Newbie when it comes to Java or anything relating to how to trouble shoot it.

Comment: The exception would seem to indicate you have exhausted the connection pool. Are you closing your connections when you're done with them? That is what returns them to the pool.